# How can i authenticate to my Identity/User Pool with Cognito Identity?

Tags: android, authentication, amazon-web-services, identity, amazon-cognito

I have been trying to solve this for a few days now but i can't figure out what the problem is.

I have a user pool and an identity pool on AWS Cognito. I have run the sample code and used it to log in and register users with Facebook and Google+ successfully. After login i am able to authenticate using the token to use SNS or the Sync services.

I have registered a user and got a token (after logging in) with Cognito Identity. However the next step is to use the token to authenticate into the identity pool. This is where i keep getting the error

I have followed the instructions from [Integrating User Pools with Amazon Cognito Identity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html) and I get a token which I then try to pass it along with the pool id to the credentials provider.

```
  credentialsProvider.clear();
  credentialsProvider.withLogins(loginMap).refresh();
```

My code fails on refresh(). At this point credentialsProvider is a AWSBasicCognitoIdentityProvider and refresh() fails in the super.refresh() which calls getIdentityId() in the abstract parent class AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider

```
@Override
public String getIdentityId() {
    if (identityId == null) {
        GetIdRequest getIdRequest = new GetIdRequest()
                .withAccountId(getAccountId())
                .withIdentityPoolId(getIdentityPoolId())
                .withLogins(loginsMap);

        appendUserAgent(getIdRequest, getUserAgent());

        GetIdResult getIdResult = cib.getId(getIdRequest);
```

No matter what values i put in the loginsMap, i get the error

> Invalid login token. Issuer doesn't match providerName

at cid.getid(getIdRequest).

Most of the code is available to download free if you create an app in the Mobile Hub and generate the code. You can then configure authentication providers - FB, Google , etc.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks.

**Edit** : Here are examples of what i have tried
The token is always the object in the map. Below are the different keys

- "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
- the User Pool id - us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx
- the User Pool ARN - cognito-idp:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:userpool/us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of what you're putting into the logins map?

Comment: @JeffBailey i have put in various Cognito Identity Pool ID formats including the full ARN and the format shown in the link above (as the key)and the token as the object

Comment: I understand, but it's a key part of the flow, especially considering the error you're seeing, and would help with debugging. Can you include what you did when following the link you provided?

Comment: Why the down vote??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK i found the answer - I was putting in the wrong key value in the loginMap.

it should be

> `cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<YOUR_USER_POOL_ID>`

as it says in the documentation linked in the question

I don't know how I didn't see that.